# controller doesn't work Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My controller doesn't seem to be working. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Main.js this is my controller :

```
Ext.define('Catalog.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
           homepanel: 'homepanel'  
        },
        control: {
            homepanel:{
                itemtap: 'showApp'
            }  
        },
        showApp: function(){
            console.log("OK");
        }
    }

});
```

Home.js this is my view:

```
Ext.define('Catalog.view.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'homepanel',
    config: {

        title: 'All',
        iconCls: 'list',
        cls: 'home',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        items:{
            title: "All Apps",
            xtype: 'list',

            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/appinfos/appicons/000/000/{id}/original/{appicon_file_name}" width="50" heigh="50" style="float:left;clear:both;"></img>',
                '<div style="margin-left: 60px;word-wrap: break-word;width:50%;">',
                '<span style="font-size:16px;">{name}</span><br>',
                '<tpl for="categories">',
                '<span style="font-size:13px;color:#7C7C7C;">{name}</span>',
                '</div>',
                '</tpl>',
                '<span></span>'
            ),
            store: {
                autoLoad: true,
                fields: ['id','name','created_at','appicon_file_name','categories'],
                sorters: 'created_at',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'jsonp',
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/appinfos.json',
                    reader:{
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty:'responseData.entries'
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**There are no errors in the console, but nothing is happening**

Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: You should try `alias: 'widget.homepanel` instead of `xtype: 'homepanel'`. and also there is no Event `itemtap` for `Ext.navigation.View`. I hope you are trying to add that event to the `list` which is child of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your showApp method is inside the config, should be:

```
Ext.define('Catalog.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            homepanel: 'homepanel'  
        },

        control: {
            homepanel:{
                itemtap: 'showApp'
            }
        }
    },

    showApp: function(){
        console.log("OK");
    }
});
```